# slice=ribbon generalization to higher genus + potential counterexamples to slice=ribbon.

Tags: knot-theory, gt.geometric-topology, 2-knots, 4-manifolds

I have two questions about the slice=ribbon conjecture.

(1) If a knot $K \hookrightarrow S^3$ has smooth slice genus $g$, you can ask if it bounds a smooth genus $g$ surface in $S^3 \times [0, -\infty)$, with the function defined by restriction to $[0, -\infty)$ being Morse on the surface without index=0 critical points (maximal points).  When $g=0$ this is just asking if the slice knot $K$ has a ribbon disc.  I was wondering if there are any knots known with $g \geq 1$ for which such a surface cannot exist.  If there are none such known, is there a topological reason why the truth of the slice=ribbon conjecture would also imply the existence of such surfaces?

(2) Are there any potential counterexamples to slice=ribbon (in the same way that there are potential counterexamples to smooth 4-d Poincare [until Akbulut kills them])?

Thanks,
Andrew.

Comment: I added a few more tags. Regarding (2) hopefully someone like Ruberman will enter the conversation.  I don't know any interesting ways of generating knots that I *know* to be slice but for which I have reason to suspect they maybe aren't ribbon.  IMO the smooth Poincare conjecture is in the same situation.  We appear to have a deficit of good ways to identify the standard smooth $S^4$. 

Comment: I believe (based on a conversation with Sylvain Cappell) that the answer to (2) is no.

Answer (score 3):

There is a paper by Gompf and Scharlemann: Fibered knots and Property 2R, II, which gives an infinite family of two component links which are smoothly slice but not obviously ribbon.

Comment: See also http://www.msp.warwick.ac.uk/gt/2010/14-04/b050.xhtml

Comment: Looks like they combined two papers together.

Answer (score 1):

This [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0166-8641%2894%2900103-A) by Gompf exhibits a potential counter-example. Has it been established that the candidate given by Gompf is not slice?